# What is causing a tiled screen during installation of 12.04 on Emachines EL1200-01e?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-12.04

I'm getting a tiled screen while installing Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit (and now 64 bit) on my EMachines EL1200-01e. No idea what could be causing this.

**EMachines EL1200-01e**

Processor

- Type AMD Athlon 64 2650e / 1.6 GHz
- 64-bit Computing Yes
- Cache Memory Type L2 cache
- Installed Size 512.0 KB
- Cache Per Processor 512 KB

Mainboard

- Chipset Type NVIDIA GeForce 6150 SE

RAM

- Installed Size 1.0 GB / 2.0 GB (max)
- Technology DDR2 SDRAM
- Form Factor DIMM 240-pin

[image]

Comment: Adding screenshots, system specifications, motherboard/chipset details will help

Comment: Won't let me add a screenshot without 10 rep. Wish I could transfer StackOverflow rep

Comment: You can upload to imgur & add the link in here. Plus system specifications, chipset etc can be mentioned

Comment: @Sathya Done and done

Comment: @Sathya Any ideas?

Comment: @Chris Does this work in the LiveCD environment, or do you get the same problem? Does this work in Windows, or other OSes?

Comment: What Lord of Time said and also: do you have normal graphics while the BIOS is loading/can you enter the BIOS setup screen with normal graphics?  I've seen dying GPUs that look like this before.

Comment: The error occurred while installing from USB. I tried just running from USB and it appeared to be working. I installed from the UI off the USB and haven't had any hiccups yet. I was waiting for more time on it to make sure its working. And a minute after I posted that, I get the same screen.

Comment: Just reset the bios to optimized defaults, will see how this runs.

Comment: @adempewolff Same tiling as screenshot occurred after bios reset. Beginning to think it's a dying GPU. How can I test this hypothesis? What are my options if it is an integrated GPU?

Comment: Sorry by my comment I didn't mean that you needed to reset the BIOS settings, I was just wondering if you ever saw tiling during the BIOS POST screen or in the BIOS setup screen--this would be a sure sign of a dying GPU.  Generally the best way to test if something is a hardware problem is to see if the same thing happens across different OSes.

Comment: @adempewolff I'll try leaving it up in BIOS to see if it does anything.

Comment: @adempewolff Did not go down for 5 hours. Any ideas?

Comment: That's a good sign.  Now try loading a more advanced graphical environment (maybe boot into the liveUSB but don't install (click "Try Ubuntu") and leave it there for awhile.  Ideally you could also boot into another OS, such as Windows, or another distribution of Linux, and test their as well.

Comment: @adempewolff No tiling yet when running Ubuntu 12.04 from USB. I'll try 10.04 to see if it works. The trouble with that version is no support for my wireless card.

Comment: Is this a lasting condition?  Or is it just a temporary effect that clears after the GUI is up and running?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same on my own EL1200 machine (for any *buntu version). I solved it by updating the BIOS. The manufacturer has an upgrade program (.exe) available.